# Calling my Model in JavaScript in html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization, erb

I have this code in my view in index.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

ActiveRecord.connect()

    var accounts = Account.find({
        all: true,
        order: 'id DESC'
    });

for (var i=0;i<accounts.length;i++)
{ 
    document.write(accounts.a_name);
    data.addRow([accounts.a_name, accounts.a_amount]);
}



    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Accounts balance distribution',
                   'width':600,
                   'height':500};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Account model is not returning any value, do you know how to change the code to make it returns values

Thank you and looking forward for your feedback
/Mohamed sami

Comment: I do not know JavaScript, i'm just using it to view a visual report

Comment: I don't see any `<%= %>` in your html.erb. I think you need them in order to pass data from Ruby to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ERB stands for Embedded Ruby, you have to embed it :

So when you write `var accounts = value`, you have to embed 'value' into `<%=` and `%>` and make sure that value is some ruby that returns the appropriate string for your Javascript (the same that you would have hard-written if it wasn't dynamic).

Comment: Here is the modified code after fixing it

    <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
         data.addRow(["<%= account.a_name %>", <%= account.a_amount %>]);
    <% end %>

Thank you